# split signal right before local minima in Numpy

Tags: numpy, split

consider the following numpy array named `final1` (signal):
[image]

I would like to separate the previous array into 4 sub arrays. The four sub arrays are separated by the moment right before the local minima, as shown in the following image:
[image]

The idea I have is to find the local minima and maxima indexes and values of the array with:

```
minimaindex = argrelextrema(final1, np.less)
maximaindex = argrelextrema(final1, np.greater)
valuesminima = final1[argrelextrema(final1, np.greater)[0]]
valuesmaxima = final1[argrelextrema(final1, np.less)[0]]
```

then sort the indexes array according to the value array, consider the 4 largest minima and finally find the closest maxima to the four minima and split the `final1` array by the indexes of those values.

I would like to know if anyone has a recomandation on how to complete the last part.

Thank you

EDIT:
This is the signal vector:
https://app.box.com/s/isog7pa3xcradzcsivn5vtx7mj8u0wp1

Comment: The main problem is differentiating the four minima you're interested in from the eleven or twelve that are on your plot. Probably the best way would be to look at the difference between a max and the next min and take the four largest ones of those

Comment: Yes, the idea is to find all the maxima and minima. Obtain the 4 minimum minima and calculate the distance of each one of the 4 minima to all the maxima, and the least distance to each minima is the maxima I am looking for each minima. My problem is regarding how to perform operations to the values vector and also to the index vector. How to optimize of sorting one vector and affect the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the accepted answer will generally do what you show on your graphs. I certainly can't get it to produce the correct answer!

Generally you will always get alternating maxima and minima with edge cases of none of one or both. You need to look at all the minima that have a maxima before them and there is no need to search for all the maxima to see which is nearest. Also you only have three cut points on your graph.

You have lots of "noise" maxima and minima which could easily scramble your results - it would be good idea to do some smoothing. Also the way you use argrelextrema is effectively the same as

```
np.where((a[:-2] > a[1:-1]) & (a[1:-1] < a[2:]))
```

(which might be quicker but you would have to +1 to index values) both would miss a turning point which happened to have two values the same.

Anyway this seems to work for me with your data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

final1 = np.loadtxt("/home/jill/Downloads/256frames_timed_SumrowSignal_1.csv", delimiter=",")
#final1 = np.convolve(final1, [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1])

minimaindex = signal.argrelextrema(final1, np.less)[0]
maximaindex = signal.argrelextrema(final1, np.greater)[0]

if minimaindex[0] < maximaindex[0]: # ensure all minima have a previous maxima
  minimaindex = minimaindex[1:]
maximaindex = maximaindex[:len(minimaindex)]
diffs = final1[maximaindex] - final1[minimaindex]
diffs_as = np.argsort(diffs)[-3:]
cut_points = maximaindex[diffs_as]
```

EDIT If you look at the attached picture you will see that you always have to have alternating maxima and minima - because of what they are.

[image]

The cases you have to look out for are where the first minimum doesn't have a maximum point to its left. That's what my line checking the first index of each does. If the maximum isn't first it chops off the first minimum. It also has to make sure that the list of maxima is truncated to the same length as minima.

The cases I don't check for are like the bottom two lines. You could just stop the process here if there aren't enough minima or maxima:

```
if minimaindex[0] < maximaindex[0]: # ensure all minima have a previous maxima
  minimaindex = minimaindex[1:]
if len(minimaindex) < 3 or len(maximaindex) < 3:
  error_message = "not enough peaks"
  return None #break, exit, whatever is relevant to the way you use the code
maximaindex = maximaindex[:len(minimaindex)]
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, the previous answer do not solve the problem but it was very helpful. Yours obtains the 3 desired cut off points, my question is how are you sure that `diffs = final1[maximaindex] - final1[minimaindex]` calculate the difference between the previous maxima of a local minima, if you have an unknown number of maxima and minima? I hope that your code can be generalized to other similar signals that I have

Answer (score 1):

You can use [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get the index of the smaller minimas:

```
valuesminima = final1[minimaindex]
# Find 4 smaller minimas
idx = np.argsort(valuesminima) # sort minima
target = idx[:4] # 4 smaller minimas

# Find all maximas
argmaximas = argrelextrema(final1, np.less)

# Extract maximas closest to the minimas
maximas = []
for minidx in minimaindex[target]: # for each minima
    dist = np.abs(argmaximas - minidx) # distance current minima
    maximas += [np.argmin(dist)] # get the closest maxima
```

Not too fancy but I guess it could work. `maximas` contains the 4 maximas closest to the smaller 4 minimas.

Comment: Hi I have an index vector and a value vector for minima and maxima. I want to perform operations with the values of maxima and minima as sorting, and this operation must also change the indexes. I think it should be similar to the code you posted

Comment: @user3025898 I've updated the answer. It finds the top 4 minimas, all the maximas. Then it finds the closest maxima for each of the minimas.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran your code, it seems that in the loop you are subtracting the indexes of the minimas to the values (argmaximas) of the maximas, is that correct?

Comment: and for some reason the maximas list returned is empty, I think it should be maximas.append() instead of maximas +=

Comment: @user3025898 `maximas += [  _  ]` has the same result as `append`. If you still have an empty list, it might be that you didn't detect minimas properly or didnt copy the code as it is.  In any case, this will only work assuming that you have detected minimas and maximas properly. As @paddyg pointed out, this is not an easy task, and something like `argrelextrema` (which I used as you did in your question) is not going to work properly. You need something more than the value of the extrema. You will need at least some central, forward or backward differences to estimate how small is the minima.

Comment: vectors of maxima and minima are correctly obtained. the current problem is that the indexes in your idx variable goes from 0 to n while what I want is that the indexes are the positions in time of the signal, as in my minimaindex variable.

Comment: @user3025898 edited again. Look at the update in the for loop using `target` to obtain the real indexes for the minima (`minimaindex[target]`). And the first line edit to get the `valuesminima` from the indexes of your `minimaindex`.

Comment: minimaindex values: `[[ 59 156 159 252 289 372 375 475 512 604 606 614 619 705 749 821]]` target values: `[[13 15 14  7 12 11 10  9  3  8  4  6  5  0  1  2]]` how are you expecting minimaindex[target] to work?

Comment: Minimavalues and target should be 1D, so `.flatten()` them. And `target = idx[:4]` so it should have ONLY 4 elements. `minimaindex[target]` should work if both are 1D. And the idea is to pic the i-th elements from minimaindex where i=target. For example, fo `target = [1, 5, 6]` it would return the 2nd, 6th and 7th elements of minimaindex.

Comment: Ok solved. the problem was the dimensions of the array.